# error: invalid path 'docker/base-images/php:7.4/Dockerfile' at git

Tags: git, github, vanilla-forums

I have this error when I try to build Vanilla Forums:

```
Cloning new copy of vanilla into C:\Users\Usuario\desktop\a\vnla\build\temp
Cloning into 'vanilla'...
error: invalid path 'docker/base-images/php:7.4/Dockerfile'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

Failed to clone branch master
```

What can happend?

I think it's a bug with git

Thanks.

I am trying to build a Vanilla Forums release.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @JimRedmond `C:\Users` ;-)

Comment: I guess git(1) should tell you that specifically `:` is not allowed in filenames on your system. The error message is pretty generic. But what do I know, might be impossible to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla-docker

> Only supports Mac OSX

Cannot be used on w64.

And no, it's not a bug in Git, it's a misfeature of your graphics environment — it doesn't allow filenames with colons and many other special characters. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+forbidden+characters

Comment: I saw it. Windows renames 'docker/base-images/php:7.4/Dockerfile' to 'docker/base-images/php_7.4/Dockerfile'.
I think I need to rename '_' to ':' but I don't know how to do it on Windows 11. Is it possible?

Comment: @LuisGarcía Impossible. Windows doesn't allow filenames with colons. Try Docker or WSL.

Comment: I have wsl installed on windows 11.